# arrayInd to show some columns for the result of which.max

Tags: r, indexing

I'm pretty sure I should be able to use arrayInd() to do this, but I'm still wrapping my head around R and I am missing something fundamental here.

I have a dataframe that includes two date columns. I calculated a new column with the difference between them. So now I have `df$before_date`, `df$after_date` and `df$days_out`.

I can do this to see the index for the maximum and minimum value in `df$days_out`:

```
> which.min(df$days_out)
[1] 18704
> which.max(df$days_out)
[1] 80183
```

And then I can go through and see the date info:

```
> df[80183, 5]
[1] "1973-12-17"
> df[80183, 6]
[1] "2010-08-13"
> df[80183, 12]
Time difference of 13388 days
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do that in one fell swoop, so I'd get a result like:

```
         df$before_date    df$after_date    df$days_out
[80183]  1973-12-17        2010-08-13       13388
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Make this a reproducible example. The answers will depend on the structure of your data, especially the class of the date columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
df[80183, c(5,6,12)]
```

Or you can calculate the max and min values in one pass:

```
df[
  c(which.max(df$days_out),which.min(df$days_out)), 
  c('days_out','before_date','after_date')
  ]
```

Comment: I edited to add the better solution. I still don't understand what arrayInd is for but this does what I needed.